# Hidden input with DOMString value

Tags: javascript, html, hidden-field

[This site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden) states that :

> input elements of type hidden let web developers include data that
> cannot be seen or modified by users when a form is submitted. Hidden inputs are completely invisible in the rendered page, and there is no way to make it visible in the page's content.

it adds:

> While the value isn't displayed to the user in the page's content, it
> is visible—and can be edited—using any browser's developer tools or
> "View Source" functionality. Do not rely on hidden inputs as a form of
> security.

So, if having this type of input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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">
```

What information can be obtained from the DOMString value? is there a way or possibility to decode the the DOMString value and get some hidden content?

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: In your case specifically, the `__VIEWSTATE` value is encrypted by ASP.NET: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/secure-asp-net-viewstate/ - so it's just a large and opaque blob. Clients cannot peek inside it (as it's encrypted) and they can't modify it (because it's HMAC signed).

Comment: Users can see what you can see. A mass of random characters. Whether an user can decode it depends on if the user knows (or can know at all) how to do it, if it's even possible (without using your private key, if there's one). If @Dai is right, then user can see this mass of data, but cannot decode, and can modiy what's sent to server, but the server will know that it was tampered with.

Comment: @FZs what would be the tools a user can use to try to decode the DOMString?

Comment: A DOMString itself isn't anything special, it's a fancy (and *very* creative) name to call strings related to an HTML (or XML) DOM. **What can decode it depends on what encoded it and how.** And again, if the things that @Dai said are right, then your server is likely already handling this properly, so your data is safe.